# Hello world with GraphQLObjectType

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am executing the following code and the result is:

```
{TestPojo={id=null, name=null}}
```

I was expecting the result to be `{TestPojo={id="1", name="Jack"}}`. What am I missing?

```
import static graphql.Scalars.GraphQLString;
import static graphql.schema.GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition;
import static graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType.newObject;

import java.util.Map;

import graphql.GraphQL;
import graphql.schema.DataFetcher;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType;
import graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sub schema to be added to parent schema
        GraphQLObjectType testPojo = newObject().name("TestPojo")
                                                .description("This is a test POJO")
                                                .field(newFieldDefinition().name("id").type(GraphQLString).build())
                                                .field(newFieldDefinition().name("name").type(GraphQLString).build())
                                                .build();
        // parent schema
        GraphQLObjectType queryType = newObject().name("helloWorldQuery")
                                                 .field(newFieldDefinition().name(testPojo.getName())
                                                                            .type(testPojo)
                                                                            .dataFetcher(new DataFetcher() {
                                                                                @Override
                                                                                public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment arg0) {
                                                                                    Object a = new GrapgQLSampleController()
                                                                                                       .greeting2();
                                                                                    return a;
                                                                                }
                                                                            })
                                                                            .build())
                                                 .build();


        GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema().query(queryType).build();
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) new GraphQL(schema).execute("{TestPojo {id,name}}")
                                                                              .getData();
        System.out.println(result);
        // Prints: {TestPojo={id=null, name=null}}
    }

    /**
     * service method 2
     *
     * @return
     */
    public TestPojo greeting2() {
        return new TestPojo("1", "Jack");
    }

    // inner pojo
    class TestPojo {
        public String id;
        public String name;

        TestPojo(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding getter methods on your `TestPojo` class as these will be called when declared on the class. Otherwise define your own `DataFetcher` on the field.

```
class TestPojo {
    public final String id;
    public final String name;

    TestPojo(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getId() {
        return id; 
    }

    String getName() { 
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to be pedagogical by fixing the code. Note that static content comes from whatever is in .staticValue("X")

```
    GraphQLObjectType testPojo = newObject().name("TestPojo")
                                            .description("This is a test POJO")
                                            .field(newFieldDefinition().type(GraphQLString).name("id").staticValue("Test1"))
                                            .field(newFieldDefinition().type(GraphQLString).name("name").staticValue("pojo1"))
                                            .build();

    GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema().query(testPojo).build();
    Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) new GraphQL(schema).execute("{id,name}")
                                                                          .getData();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Will print {id=Test1, name=pojo1}

Can update the example using DataFetcher when I have time

Comment: this answer did not answer the question asked